# Comparability of multivariate vs multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, matlab, multivariate-regression

I have 3 layers of data [in individual columns] indicating different characteristics of resistance of vegetation to stress across a city. I have another layer of median income for my study area. I would like to see if income has any impact on vegetation's response to stress.

This seems like a problem for multivariate linear regression-- where I would see if income influences vegetation.

However, I'm unclear how to solve for all the information (r^2, p-value, etc) that you get using multiple regression when using mvregress in Matlab, but I *do* know how to solve a multiple linear regression.

Wouldn't the relationship between the plant's response to income be the same whether you use a multivariate or a multiple regression? If I were to use a multiple linear regression, it seems I would be asking how a plant's response to stress affects income, which doesn't make sense. However, I imagine the relationship between stress response and income would be the same either way.

Would it be reasonable for me to use a multiple regression in this case, or do I need to use a multivariate regression? Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: In multiple regression the dependent variable is univariate.  In mulivariate regression it is a n-dimensional vector.

Comment: You could do the multiple regression but call it multivariate regression for clarity since the two are the same in this special case. In either analysis, the linear combination of the characteristics that correlates highest with income will be found.